# Preparing paper with bibliography for ASL

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am preparing an ASL document, but do not understand the instructions in [DOCUMENT PREPARATION FOR ASL PUBLICATIONS](http://aslonline.org/files/AuthorResourcesTEX-files/asldoc.pdf) well enough to get the bibliography up and running. I understand how to set up the asl.cls, and I am familiar with using bibtex under nat.bib. But I do not understand the role of asl.bst, and am not able to set up a MWE for how to write my document.

Could someone help we with an MWE or other advice to solve my problems?

Answer (score 1):

The `.bst` file is the bibliography style file.

An MWE could be:

```
\documentclass{asl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{test,
    author  = {Author},
    title   = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    volume  = {1},
    pages   = {1--10},
    year    = {2020}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\bibliographystyle{asl}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I saved it so I got this in my folder:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e70z24eit8gh5po/Screenshot%202020-03-24%2013.15.47.png?dl=0

Comment: But compiling and building only gives me this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0twhlpiwu1s25cg/Screenshot%202020-03-24%2013.18.41.png?dl=0

Comment: What is my mistake?

Comment: It looks like you didn't run `bibtex document`. Another thing you could check is your file `asl.bst`. With 171 KB it's much larger than the version I'm using. The version I found on http://aslonline.org/journals/author-resources/ is in html format: http://aslonline.org/files/AuthorResourcesTEX-files/ASLbst.html. Copy past the code from the website into a text file and call it `asl.bst`. You should get a file of ~66 KB.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. However, I ended up with a very large asl.bst - 244kp. I had difficulties placing an asl.bst in the directory, and the method I used was to save it as asl.bst.pages with the pages program of MacOS, and then edit the name to asl.bsl; maybe there is a better way?

Comment: With Pages you can "File" > "Export To" > "Plain Text…". Or on macOS you can use TextEdit, select "Format" > "Make Plain Text" to make a plain text file. I don't know your TeX-Editor, but that saves files typically as plain text.

Comment: I was able to export as you explained with pages, and I obtained an asl.bst-file at  about 70kb. Unfortunately, it did not resolve the problem and still just two question marks are shown after trying to compile and build.

I use tex-studio.

Comment: Did BibTeX run through without error? Did you get a `.bbl` file in your working directory?

Comment: Yes there is a bbl-file, with size 4 bytes.

Comment: There were no error messages.

Comment: Ok. Mine is 275 bytes. If you look in the `.blg` file. Does it have any error messages?

Comment: What program do I use to open .blg?

Comment: TextEdit for example

Comment: There were some error messages, I'd say: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7b1y4adwra8oh6/blg%20file.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105923/discussion-between-luki-and-sapiens).